# Getting 'choice' to work in Highline Ruby Gem without error and getting variable from it

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-interface, rubygems, highline

I'm having a couple of problems using Highline in Ruby, and trying to get the choice element, [detailed here](http://highline.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/highline/examples/menus.rb), to work.

1. At the moment the following code produces the error 
   "error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). Use --trace to view backtrace"
2. How do I get the variable out of choice? At the moment I have the 'do' setup, but I have no idea about how to get the variable the user has chosen out and into a variable for use elsewhere.

Sorry if this is a bit beginner, I'm brand new to ruby and this is my first project, in at the deep end.

Thanks in advance.

```
if agree("Are these files going to be part of a set? ") 
      set_title = ask("Title: ")
      set_desc = ask("Description:")
      set_genre = ask("Genre: ")
      set_label = ask("Record Label: ")
      set_date = ask_for_date("Release Date (yy-mm-dd): ")
      set_label = ask("EAN/UPC: ")
      set_buy = ask("Buy this set link: ")
      set_tags = ask_for_array("Tags (seperated by space): ")

      # Sort out license
      choose do |menu|
        menu.prompt = "Please choose the license for this set?  "

        menu.choices(:all_rights_reserved, :cc_by) do 
          # put the stuff in a variable
        end
      end
    end # End setup set
```

Comment: Which line gives you a problem, exactly? The `choose` section works fine in Ruby 1.8 or 1.9. The `ask_for_date` seems to be a custom method, as is `ask_for_array`, so can't help you there...

Comment: This is a transcript of my session:


 Alex-Andrewss-MacBook-Pro:SoundCloud-CLI alex$ ruby sc.rb upload /Users/alex/SoundCloud-CLI
 Are these files going to be part of a set? y
 Title: hello
 Description:
 hello
 Genre: hello
 Record Label: hello
 Release Date (yy-mm-dd): 09-10-10
 EAN/UPC: hello
 Buy this set link: hello
 Tags (seperated by space): hello gello
 error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). Use --trace to view backtrace

Thanks very much for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

1) Not enough information provided (see my comment)

2) Use a block parameter:

```
menu.choices(:all_rights_reserved, :cc_by) do |chosen|
  puts "Item chosen: #{chosen}"
end
```

You can also split your choices:

```
menu.choice(:all_rights_reserved) do
  puts "Chosen: All Rights Reserved"
  #...
end

menu.choice(:cc_by) do
  puts "Chosen: CC by"
  #...
end
```

Comment: The solution to 2) works beautifully thanks.

With regard to 1) I copied the following to a fresh file.

    require 'rubygems'

    require 'commander/import'

        choose do |menu|
            menu.prompt = "Please choose the license for this set?  "     
            menu.choices(:all_rights_reserved, :cc_by) do |chosen|
                puts "Item chosen: #{chosen}"
            end
        end

This fails with the following errors:
    scratch.rb:5:in `choose': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Change the line to require 'commander' and it works, but other things break